# How do i get nextval without advancing the cursor?

Tags: postgresql

How do i get nextval without advancing the cursor in PostgreSQL?

This doesn't work:

```
pgdb=# SELECT curval('schemas.category_category_id_seq');
ERROR:  function curval(unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT curval('schemas.category_category_id_seq');
           ^
```

HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PostgreSQL's nextval() function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) is safe. But currval()+1 isn't.

Comment: The problem is I'm instering into cascade tables, in order to insert into first I have to insert into second the `nextval` of first and afterwards insert into second, ugh...

Comment: That doesn't make sense. It does make sense to insert nextval() into the first table, and insert the same value into the second.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, your function name is just wrong.  It is "currval".  See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/how-do-i-use-currval-in-postgresql-to-get-the-last-inserted-id

BTW, if you can assume your sequence just increments by one, you can do:

```
select currval('schemas.category_category_id_seq') + 1;
```